# Finding a nonlinear mapping between two sets of data points

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I have two sets of data points; effectively, one is from a preimage and the other from its image, but I do not know the rule between the two. This rule/function is nonlinear.

I've collected many data points of corresponding locations on both images, and I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to find a more complete mapping. That is, does anyone know the best way to find a mapping from R^2 to R^2 with an extensive set of sample points. This mapping is one-to-one and onto.

My goal is to use the data I've found to find a polynomial function that takes in some x,y coordinate from the preimage, and outputs the shifted coordinates.

edit: I have sample points along the domain and their corresponding points in the image, but not for every point in the domain. I want to be able to input any point (only integer values) in the domain and output the shifted point.

Comment: There are infinitely many mappings that map a set _A_ to a set _B_... You need to decide what features you want the mapping to have so that a unique solution exists

Comment: Thanks for the response; I think I see what you mean. I have adjusted the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think *polynomial* is easy (or easy to guarantee is a bijection). The obvious thing to do is to

1. Construct the delaunay triangulation of the known points in the domain.
2. For each delaunay triangle the mapping is just the linear mapping which interpolates the map on the vertices.
3. Then, when you have a random point, look up its delaunay triangle, and apply the requisite map.

I believe that all of the above can be done via [`scipy.spatial.delaunay`.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html)

Answer (score 0):

The transformation you're trying to find sounds a lot like what's accomplished in Geographic Information Systems using a technique called rubber-sheeting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubbersheeting

Igor Rivin's description of a process using a Delaunay triangulation is pretty much the solution that's used in such systems.  Some systems will use a Barycentric coordinate system rather than a linear mapping to try to reduce the appearance of triangle-related artifacts in the transformed image.

What you are describing also sounds a bit like the "morphing" special effect used in video.   Maybe a web search on that topic would turn up some leads for you.